# What are the disadvantages of SPF?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, spf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SPF - should I implement?](https://serverfault.com/questions/301895/spf-should-i-implement)

In relation [to this question](https://serverfault.com/q/301895/72020) and I've also been warned against it myself by an ISP tech, what are some of the common reasons against using SPF, whether valid or otherwise?

Comment: Ask the person warning you against implementing it.  To my knowledge properly implementing SPF has no negative impact. IMPROPER implementation certainly has the potential to cause problems.  The burden of proof here is on the guy alleging an issue - I'm sure people will be more than happy to refute anything he brings up...

Comment: @voretaq7: It was more than 12 months ago and I can't find the relevant email either.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you set up an SPF record i have set SPF records for my domains for a while now 
and i see no negative impact of any kind , the whole idea behind SPF records is to HELP you .

the comment by Marcel about creating the SPF record properly is obcourse a good idea.

you can refer to the following "Wizards" that assist you in creating your spf records based on the input you provide.

http://www.microsoft.com/mscorp/safety/content/technologies/senderid/wizard/default.aspx
http://www.mailradar.com/spf/

Good luck :)

Regards,
Eli B.